# Opening Lync 2013 Mobile Client from Third Party iOS App

Tags: ios, url-scheme, lync-2013

I have installed Lync 2013 mobile client in iOS and I know that executing lync:// url scheme like below

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"lync://"]];
```

will open the installed Lync app but I would like to know more about the other URL parameters that can be used in custom url scheme for performing other actions like for example

1. Automatic login using the credentials
2. Open a meeting URL

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear to be possible at this point.

[Somebody asked a question on Technet really closely related to yours two years ago](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4af68bf9-abd2-4aa5-a31e-1a6e9ac0c540/can-lync-2010-on-ios-be-opened-from-another-application-or-url-schema-lyncdomainusername?forum=ocsclients) and got an answer that URL parameters are not supported with the Lync client on iOS.

[And here's another question asking about parameters](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/71a7e5f0-b793-48e7-be64-3a6e4e40061d/ios-lync-url-scheme-parameters?forum=ocsmobility) with pretty much the same result.

Sounds like you should file a feature request with Microsoft to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation lists all the scheme URIs and the parameters that you can pass.

**For Lync 2010, you can use:**

Lync://

**For Lync 2013, you can use any of the following:**

Tel:+14255550101 -> Opens a phone-only view with +14255550101.

Callto:tel:+ 14255550101 -> Opens a phone-only view with +14255550101.

Callto:sip:name@example.com -> Opens a phone-only view with name@example.com

sip:name@example.com -> Opens a Conversation window with name@example.com

conf:sip:https://meet.contoso.com/name/7322994

Full details can be found on MSDN [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376%28v=ocs.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sip://"]];
```