# How can I launch the Lync client from custom Android app via Intent?

Tags: android, lync

Our organization has Lync as primary channel for IM. Now that everyone is about to get a mobile phone we need a way to have the custom mobile apps display presence and initiate chat sessions. It is almost the way Facebook client does it with Facebook Messenger.

I cannot find anything anywhere that shows how to any of those. I can deal w/o presence but it is a must to start the chat.

Note I don't want to go against UCWA and write another chat client. Lync for Android is good enough. I just need to figure out what the proper Intent and parameters are.

Answer (score 1):

You could always open your Lync client by opening a URL that starts with the letters "`lync://`".

[This URL scheme works just as well on iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221088/opening-lync-2013-mobile-client-from-third-party-ios-app).

Comment: This works technically speaking but in example when I do sip:// and it prompts which SIP client I should use - Skype, Lync etc.. I need tighter integration without the choice. If I just use lync:// it just starts lync and that's it. I need to take it to the conversation window

Comment: why are you using "`sip://`" when I said "`lync://`" should work?

Comment: Typed it in the wrong window. Lync:// just starts the client. I need to go to the conversation window

Comment: sip://villyg@foo.com actually starts the conversation window unless there is another SIP client installed..then it gets goofy

Comment: @VillyG: its not opening the user window , if I am giving  Uri detail = Uri.parse("lync://"+emailID);